# i need to hide password input fields randomly in primefaces jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on two step authentication using jsf primefaces, in first step user enter   captcha, and next step user have to enter 8 digit password. i want to    hide password fields on random basis. e.g if user password is    12345678 system should ask to enter 2nd,3rd,6th and 7th character of    the password and other fields are disable. field would be disable on random basis. Code is given below as well as attached screen

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{logBean.passFields}" varStatus="loop">
  <p:password styleClass="Box key1" size="1" maxlength="1" disabled="false" id="password${loop.index}" value="#{logBean.passFields[loop.index]}">
 </p:password>
</ui:repeat>
```

[Password Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVQpd.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to disable 4 fields every time randomly for password.

Comment: What's about `<p:password styleClass="Box key1" size="1" maxlength="1" disabled="#{logBean.toDisable(loop.index)}" id="password${loop.index}"...` and a function `boolean toDisable(int idx) {}` in your logBean which decides which field is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corectly, you want to render x amount of `<p:password` components right ? then maybe you can just call a method that randomly returns a boolean:

facelet:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="20" var="i">
  #{i}: <h:inputSecret rendered="#{indexBean.randomRender()}" />
 <br />
</c:forEach>
```

Bean:

```
public boolean randomRender(){
    int ran = (int)(Math.random()*9999);                
    return ran%2 != 0;
}
```

Instead of using the `c:foreach` you just use your way for looping through some collection:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{logBean.passFields}" varStatus="loop"> ...
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but i think you couldn't understood wel. I have fixed 8 <p:password components and i want to disable 4 components randomly every time. then in bean class i need to concat all and compare with password

Comment: @T.Hassan: You have a weird functional requirement

Comment: What I mean is it is hard to understand why yu would want this. And the solution is kind of basic

Comment: i am implementing two step authentication and i need to make password more secure so that i want to make fields disable randomly. e.g if the password is 12...8 . system should allow user to enter only 4 digit and others fields are disable.

Answer (score 0):

Bean class

```
private String password = null;
private int guessCtr = 4;
private String[] passFields;
private String[] newpassFields;

public LogBean(){
    password = "12345678";
    //create your password array
    passFields = password.split("");        
    //if using java 8. remove this line and use the passFields instead.
    //this is just a workaround to remove the first empty element result of .split()
    newpassFields = Arrays.copyOfRange(passFields, 1, passFields.length);

    //create an array of int index
    int[] index = new int[newpassFields.length];
    for(int i=0; i<index.length; i++){
        index[i] = i;
    }
    //store the indexes in a list for the shuffle method.
    //you can use any other method to do your randomization here
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : index) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    //use sublist here to get only the first 4(guessCtr) elements
    list = list.subList(list.size()-(list.size()-guessCtr), list.size());

    //set the 4 random values to '' and will also be used for the disabled logic.
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        newpassFields[list.get(i)] = "";
    }
}
```

Page

```
<h:form>
<ui:repeat value="#{logBean.newpassFields}" varStatus="loop">   
    <p:inputText type="password" disabled="#{logBean.newpassFields[loop.index] != ''}" value="#{logBean.newpassFields[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
<h:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{logBean.submit}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Your submit should now just convert the newpassFields to String and compare it the password.